# Cloned Windows 10 partition on the same drive fails to boot

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a Surface Pro 4 with a 256GB SSD running the current version of Windows 10, 1703 as of the time of writing. The SSD is partitioned as follows:

- C: Windows system partition containing the usual suspects, 65GB
- D: Data partition containing relocated user folders, 100GB
- E: Expendable partition containing VM page file, temp dirs, app caches, 10GB
- The normal hidden system and recovery partitions
- Contiguous unallocated space, 65GB

I used Partition Wizard to copy/clone the Windows partition into the unallocated space. I used EasyBCD to adjust the boot menu and rename the partitions so I can tell them apart. Both partitions show up on the boot screen. I can successfully boot into the original partition and everything works as it always did. I can mount the cloned partition on a different drive letter and access it just fine.

However, when I attempt to boot the cloned partition, the boot process fails to complete. Specifically, it gets to the point where it displays the login screen (the one with the user picture and password entry box) for a split-second, then it reverts to a blank screen with the circular chasing dots in the lower-center, and there it sits, unresponsive to any user input. I've let it run overnight and it never progresses further.

I've tried 1 or 2 other partition managers and gotten the same result. I've tried the same procedure on an older, home-built desktop system and also gotten the same result, so it doesn't appear to be hardware dependent. I have done this successfully many times in the past on previous versions of Windows.

I have also installed a clean copy of Windows 10 from an ISO into the unallocated partition, and dual-booting those two independently installed copies works just fine. No activation problems.

Why does the cloned copy fail to finish booting, and what if anything can I try to fix it? Any debugging advice is certainly welcome.

BTW, my reason for doing this is so that I can install the Insider Preview on the cloned partition, and actually use it to do real work without having to spend hours and hours and hours reinstalling and reconfiguring my work environment on top of a clean install.

UPDATE: The failure description above is from the desktop system experiment. The Surface behaves differently. It does not show the login screen but goes straight to black. Instead of the chasing dots, it shows the mouse pointer flickering back and forth between normal and busy. The Type Cover trackpad, a wired mouse and the touch screen will all move the mouse pointer normally. Holding down the power button results in the "swipe down to shut down" visual which appears to work, but the system doesn't actually turn off. Holding the power button for longer does shut it down.

Also, the Volume Serial Numbers of the original and cloned partitions are *different*.

Comment: Try `sfc /scannow` from safe mode or a recovery command prompt.

Comment: I deleted the partition and started over. Before cloning I scanned the C: drive from recovery mode and got `did not find any integrity violations.` I cloned the partition and scanned it from recovery _before_ trying to boot from it and got `no violations` again. I then booted the clone and it failed. Back in recovery mode, I scanned it again but this time got `could not perform the requested operation.` I presume that means that it found something wrong and failed to fix it. Does `sfc` leave a log file anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it leaves a log somewhere in `D:\Windows\Logs`, but it's extremely large because it logs every single operation.

Comment: Just to be clear, the log should be in the log dir of the instance of windows being scanned, not in the boot partition where windows is running from in recovery mode? None of the timestamps seem to match. Going to try again tomorrow, but delete the log dir first. Thx.

Comment: Running `sfc` does not resolve the problem. Log file is `%windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log` but doesn't contain any useful info in this case. Running `sfc` in recovery mode doesn't produce a log file anywhere that I could find.

Comment: This is a very strange anomaly, but unfortunately I have no more tips. Perhaps it detects that the configuration is different and wants to show you the registration screen, but it gets stuck trying to load that screen as it is waiting for an online component. Plug the computer in through Ethernet?